# Plot only "not None" values at a scatter graph

Tags: python, scatter-plot

I have 2 lists:

```
list1 = [-1, -6, None, -8, None, None, -2] #axis y
list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] #axis x
```

I need to plot on a scatter graph only the not None value (-1, -6...) but at the same time show all the values on list2 on the axis X.

I also need to keep the Y-axis in the same order as shown (-1, -6...).
can someone help me, please?

Comment: I don't think I understood your question. How do you want to show values in list2 if they are not plotted because their counterparts in list1 are None?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [plot a specific points with colors on a scatter graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61853077/plot-a-specific-points-with-colors-on-a-scatter-graph)

Comment: If you have consecutive x values, and you want to use every x value even if the corresponding y value is missing... how is this a *scatter* plot?

Answer (score 0):

To filter out all the `None` values in `list1` you could use a snippet like this

```py
does_not_contain_none = list(filter(lambda x: x is not None, list1))
```

Note: This will preserve the original order of the elements

Answer (score 0):

## Step by step

```
zipped = zip(list1, list2)  # make pairs: (-1, 1), (-6, 2), (None, 3), ...
filtered = filter(lambda x: x[0] is not None, zipped)  # filter all pairs where first element is None
ys, xs = zip(*filtered)  # reverse zip operation but on the filtered data
```

## More compact

```
filtered = (pair for pair in zip(list1, list2) if pair[0] is not None)
ys, xs = zip(*filtered)
```